# New to PhoneGap, need guidance to get started

Tags: javascript, cordova

Ok, I've been in planning for developing a PhoneGap app for a few months, and it's come time for me to start coding. There are a few things I am confused about that I need to clear up before I can get going, because things don't seem to be going well.

To begin, I am using PhoneGap to build this app because I plan to release it to multiple platforms (primarily iOS and Android) and based on the tutorials for Objective-C that I've read, I'd much rather use JavaScript/jQuery/jQueryMobile to develop the app. If anyone thinks that these are not appropriate reasons to be using PhoneGap and that I should be using something else, please let me know.

I seem to be misunderstanding some things that are apparently self-explanatory about PhoneGap, and after hours of scouring the internet looking for answers, I can't seem to find anyone else who has had the same problems as me. To clarify, I am quite comfortable with my HTML/CSS/JavaScript skills. I literally just need to GET STARTED.

- I see the terms PhoneGap and Cordova used interchangeably. From the sources I've seen they are pretty much synonymous, but I'd like to know what the ACTUAL difference is.
- I'm fairly certain I have PhoneGap installed. I can run PhoneGap commands and I was able to get the basic Hello World application and run it on an iPhone emulator. I then began to make changes to the files and rebuilt and reinstalled to test it and it replaced all my changes with the original application. I'm not sure what I did wrong, but I feel like I'm missing something.
- Can I use other JavaScript libraries like jQuery or jQuery Mobile with PhoneGap? I'm not sure what I'm limited to, or if I can use them, what the best way is to do that.
- I've seen example applications that were able to use PHP even though many sources say that you can't. How is this done?
- Can multiple pages be used or is it better to modify one to make it seem like there are multiple pages?

Any other suggestions on exactly how to get started will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Only edit the files in your www folder, because when you run

```
phonegap build ios
```

it copies files from the www folder into the various different platform folders (depending on which platforms you've added) and compiles an application out of them.

- http://www.tricedesigns.com/ - lots of sample apps and tutorials
- http://www.raymondcamden.com/ - ditto
- http://coenraets.org/blog/ - ditto
- http://devgirl.org/ - tutorials
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap - official group

Comment: Yes, I got this after awhile. I didn't realize that there were two sets of www folders, one in the top-level dir and one generated from that in each platform's folder. I was working in the latter, so all my work was replaced by the top-level stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cordova is the open source community driven version of the framework, Phonegap is a "snapshot"  of cordova at a given point that Adobe specifically supports through it's build service, there are small differences but on the whole they're more or less identical in feature set and use.

You can use any JS libraries you want, and you'd use them exactly as you would normally on the web.

PHP code cannot be used inside a phonegap/cordova app but there's nothing to stop you loading data from external sources.

Regarding multiple pages, I'd generally stick with a single page and just show/hide parts of it as needed, just so you're not having to deal with re-loading libraries on each page load and adding overhead to the app itself.

As for where to start - there's a few good books out there but you could do worse than to give this tutorial a go..

http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was pretty sure on most of that, I just needed explicit verification. Also, if you don't mind me asking, where did you find that tutorial? It seems much more in-depth than most tutorials I've seen, and I've looked through all the ones I found via Google.
Also, btw, I think you meant Apache, not Adobe. Oh, never mind. You did mean Adobe.

Comment: not sure how I stumbled on that tutorial, just trawling I suppose - It caught my eye for the reason it was more of a "real world" scenario that you're typical tutorials.